# 1e5 which is equivalent to 10^5 . Is this value represents double or int in java. Can You please elaborate the concept

Tags: java

This Code is giving error that lossy conversion from double to int.

int[] ans=new int[1e5+1];

Comment: Please read the Literals section of https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: So it's a double. Surely this is obvious?

Answer (score 2):

The concept is simple: 1E5 is a 'double' floating-point number in Java because the [Java language specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-3.html#jls-FloatingPointLiteral) says it is.

Meanwhile, an array size must be integral, and the compiler is telling you that.  If you really want to use a floating-point number there, you need to cast to `int`.  However, it's easier to just write 100000.